# Apple Mail to Windows Outlook Migration

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, migration

I am stuck in a situation here. I am migrating my email database from Apple Mail to Windows Outlook. Plenty of my emails were on the online web mail that were automatically downloaded when I signed in Outlook for windows but there are many emails that are offline and stored in apple mail. How can I migrate those emails from Apple mail to Windows Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand that every email client used different email formats while saving/archiving their email database. For example Apple Mail archives its email database in .mbox format.

On the other hand Outlook for windows can imports or archives its email database in .pst file.

So, in order to migrate your email database from Apple Mail to Windows Outlook you will need to convert .mbox email database files into .pst.

Unfortunately there is no free solution to this problem. There are paid application available online for such conversion. I am mentioning one that appeared on top ranks for my search of "Apple Mail to PST" on google.

http://applemailtopst.com/
(I haven't used this application)

Comment: Seems like an interesting application. I have downloaded its trial version, I wished there was some free solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires to configure your 2 E-mail clients so as to connect to your servers with the IMAP protocol.

Next with `Mail` you will transfer all your Mac resident mailboxes onto created ones on your mailserver.

These newly created mailboxes will be directly accessible from `Outlook`. If you want to bring them back as resident mailboxes, you will have to create new resident mailboxes and transfer your mailserver mailboxes into your resident ones.

This double transfer will make both a content format translation, and a mailboxes index upgrade.

The whole operation will require approximately a quarter of an hour per gigabyte of mailbox.